# downloading with service and showing progress bar

Tags: android, android-service, android-progressbar

I have to download a file and show the progress as the download starts. In the mean while user can go to any other activity.So, i think the best way is to download with the help of service.

But how to send the progress update.

I got this code

[Sameer Z. answer to download from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303365/need-help-in-downloading-in-background-images-in-android/6326839#6326839)

but how to show the progress.

Comment: but the user goes from one tab to other..and if the activity finishes then async task will also stop.

Comment: ok use a service and you can take the call back using an interface

Answer (score 1):

You can design a custom notification, which will show the progress in the notification bar. That is the best way to show download progress if downloading from a service.

What you want is here: 
http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/show-progressbar-in-notification-area-like-google-does-when-downloading-from-android
Also check :
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomExpandedView

Answer (score -1):

`AsyncTask` will solve your problem

See this link:  [Threads, Handlers and AsyncTask](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)